# How to remove duplicate add rows in jqgrid in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

My jqgrid is populated with 3 duplicate forms for adding a row to the grid. What could have caused this to repeat that row multiple times times in jquery. How to remove the duplicate row. I want to have only one add row.

[image]

Comment: Probably check the server side data that you are passing to jqgrid, or else check with the ID of the row that you are using to add row , it should be unique

Comment: The id of these duplicate rows are same for all the rows. This is the id for all <tr> of these rows "tr_shipmentConvFreightId".

Comment: Any idea? The server response is coming proper. I am just getting two rows from the server for this grid.